# How to introduce constraints using Python itertools.product()?

Tags: python, python-itertools, combinatorics, more-itertools

The following script generates 4-character permutations of set `s` and outputs to file:

```py
import itertools


s = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '!']

l = list(itertools.product(s, repeat=4))

with open('output1.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in l:
        f.write(''.join([str(v) for v in i]) + '\n')
```

**Output:**

```
...
11!1
11!2
11!3
11!4
11!!
...
```

**How are constraints introduced such as:**

- No permutation should start with `'!'`
- The 3rd character should be `'3'`
- etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `repeat` parameter is meant to be used when you *do* want the same set of options for each position in the sequence. Since you don't, then you should just use positional arguments to give the options for each position in the sequence. ([docs link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product))

For your example, the first letter can be any of `['1', '2', '3', '4']`, and the third letter can only be `'3'`:

```py
import itertools as it

s = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '!']
no_exclamation_mark = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
only_3 = ['3']

l = it.product(no_exclamation_mark, s, only_3, s)
```

@Kelly Bundy wrote the same solution in a comment, but simplified using the fact that strings are sequences of characters, so if your options for each position are just one character each then you don't need to put them in lists:

```py
l = it.product('1234', '1234!', '3', '1234!')
```

Comment: About the `repeat` parameter, the doc says "To compute the product of an iterable with itself" and you say "the same set of options for each position", and until earlier today I thought so as well, but... `product(A, B, repeat=2)` actually works, too. It's almost equivalent to `product(A, B, A, B)`. (I'll leave the "almost" as a little riddle :-)

Comment: @KellyBundy Interesting; I believe the difference you're referring to is that when `A` and/or `B` will be consumed when iterating, `product(A, B, repeat=2)` consumes `A` and `B` and then reuses the results as expected, whereas `product(A, B, A, B)` tries to consume them twice, resulting in an empty product.

Comment: That's indeed what I meant. Too easy for you :-). Anyway, kinda odd that the doc text doesn't mention `repeat` with multiple iterables (and makes it sound like it's only for one), only the "roughly equivalent" Python code there hints at it.

Comment: @kaya3, thanks for taking the time to create and explaining the solution. This really helped!

Answer (score 2):

Don't convert the result to a list. Instead, filter it using a generator comprehension:

```
result = itertools.product(s, repeat=4)
result = (''.join(word) for word in result)
result = (word for word in result if not word.startswith('!'))
result = (word for word in result if word[2] == '3')
```

The filtering will not be executed until you actually read the elements from `result`, such as converting it to a list or using a for-loop:

```
def f1(x):
    print("Filter 1")
    return x.startswith('A')
    
def f2(x):
    print("Filter 2")
    return x.endswith('B')
    
words = ['ABC', 'ABB', 'BAA', 'BBB']

result = (word for word in words if f1(word))
result = (word for word in result if f2(word))
print('No output here')

print(list(result))
print('Filtering output here')
```

This will output

```
No output here
Filter 1
Filter 2
Filter 1
Filter 2
Filter 1
Filter 1
['ABB']
Filtering output here
```

Answer (score 0):

The `itertools.product` function can't handle the kinds of constraints you describe itself. You can probably implement them yourself, though, with extra iteration and changes to how you build your output. For instance, to generate a 4-character string where the third character is always `3`, generate a 3-product and use it to fill in the first, second and fourth characters, leaving the third fixed.

Here's a solution for your two suggested constraints. There's not really a generalization to be made here, I'm just interpreting each one and combining them:

```
import itertools

s = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '!']

for i in s[:-1]: # skip '!'
    for j, k in itertools.product(s, repeat=2): # generate two more values from s
        print(f'{i}{j}3{k}')
```

This approach avoids generating values that will need to be filtered out. This is *a lot* more efficient than generating all possible four-tuples and filtering the ones that violate the constraints. The filtering approach will often do many times more work, and it gets proportionally much worse the more constraints you have (since more and more of the generated values will be filtered).

Comment: `product('1234', '1234!', '3', '1234!')` does handle them, no?

Comment: Hm. I'll see if I can translate your solution. I was being very general in the OP. The real problem has a set `s` of 27 characters, a `repeat=6` and constraints like: `Position 1 and 2 must be '.', '*' or '_'. Position 3 must be '8', '1' or '-'. Etc`

Comment: Its too bad that something like the [`itertools.dropwhile()` or the `.filterfalse()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile) functions can't be used...

Comment: It's not impossible to use filtering approaches, but as the number of possible outcomes rises, generating them all (before filtering) can become prohibitively costly. Trying to generate the right set of values directly is usually more efficient, but it's much harder to generalize.

Comment: @SeaDude Why do you keep talking about using `repeat` when you apparently *don't* want to repeat? Why not use `'.*_'` for positions 1 and 2, use `'81-'` for position 3, etc? What are your constraints that *can't* be done like this?

Comment: I'm not sure how to get a 6-character series without using `itertools.product(s, repeat=6)`. `..1...` would be a valid. In that case, repeating takes place. Do you have a solution you'd like to share?

Comment: @SeaDude Then you didn't read its documentation and didn't read my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

Itertools' product does not have an integrated filter mechanism.  It will generate all permutations brutally and you will have to filter its output (which is not very efficient).

To be more efficient you would need to implement your own (recursive) generator function so that you can short-circuit the generation as soon as one of the constraint is not met (i.e. before getting to a full permutation):

```
def perm(a,p=[]):
    # constraints applied progressively
    if p and p[0] == "!": return
    if len(p)>= 3 and p[2]!= '3': return
    
    # yield permutation of 4
    if len(p)==4: yield p; return
    
    # recursion (product)
    for x in a:
        yield from perm(a,p+[x])
```

Output:

```
s = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '!']
for p in perm(s): print(p)
        
['1', '1', '3', '1']
['1', '1', '3', '2']
['1', '1', '3', '3']
['1', '1', '3', '4']
['1', '1', '3', '!']
['1', '2', '3', '1']
['1', '2', '3', '2']
['1', '2', '3', '3']
...
['4', '4', '3', '3']
['4', '4', '3', '4']
['4', '4', '3', '!']
['4', '!', '3', '1']
['4', '!', '3', '2']
['4', '!', '3', '3']
['4', '!', '3', '4']
['4', '!', '3', '!']
```